# Read XML file to an already existing database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to read an XML-file into a database table that already exists.

The problem is that the XML-tags and the database columns doesn't have the same name although they have the same datatype. Therefore I'd like to "translate" the XML-tags into the database columns so that the the input to the database becomes possible. 
I'm not sure how to do that however.

Here is what I've done so far.

```
 static void writeToDatabase()
        {
            XmlDocument doc= new XmlDocument();
            try {
                //Reading the xml
                  doc.Load("C:\\Temp\navetout.xml");


                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

               //Code here to read the xml into an already existing database table?



                } 

            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

The database is located on another server, I've included this on the `app.config`

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CS"
    connectionString="Data Source=tsrv2062;Initial Catalog=BUMS;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Let's say for an example that the XML file has the tags "*Name*" while the database table column has the column "*Firstname*".

Before reading the the XML data into the database table, I suppose the XML-tags has to be translated into the Database table column. In this case "*Firstname*".

Can anyone help me out with this "translation" and the reading into the database table.

**UPDATE**

XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>7527245452542</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>20</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>skjdgnsdng</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>sdsdgsdgs</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20060512</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>56</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>77</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>PÅLNGE 6:38</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>sgdsdgsdgs</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>78965</PostNr>
          <Postort>PÅLÄNG</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>46464545</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>764846846</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>45465654645</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>00</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>NEDERKALIX</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

These are the columns of the database table:

```
PersonalIdentityNumber
ProtectedIdentity
ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber
UnregistrationReason
UnregistrationDate
MessageComputerComputer
GivenNameNumber
FirstName
MiddleName
LastName
NotifyName
NationalRegistrationDate
NationalRegistrationCountyCode
NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode
NationalRegistrationCoAddress
NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1
NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2
NationalRegistrationPostCode
NationalRegistrationCity
NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress
NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode
NationalRegistrationNotifyCity
ForeignDistrubtionAddress1
ForeignDistrubtionAddress2
ForeignDistrubtionAddress3
ForeignDistrubtionCountry
ForeignDate
BirthCountyCode
BirthParish
ForeignBirthCity
CitizenshipCode
CitizenshipDate
Email
Telephone
Mobiletelephone
Gender
NotNewsPaper
Note
StatusCode
NationalRegistrationCode
RegistrationDate
LastUpdatedFromNavet
TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1
TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2
TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3
TemporaryDistrubtionCountry
Password
VisibilityLevel
LastChangedBy
LastChangedDate
SeamanIdentity
Category
```

Here for an example, the `<PersonNr>` tagg and the databse column `PersonalIdentityNumber` are the same.
The column that doesn't match with the XML-tags are supposed to returning `null`.

Comment: Why did you set the `sql-server` tag? Do you just want to read an existing XML file into your C# application? Then you write that you want to add this content to an existing DataTable, but you are creating a new DataTable instance... Is this an existing table withing SQL Server? If so: Wouldn't it be easier to create a Stored Procedure within SQL Server, accepting the XML as input. There you can shred the XML with any naming and do what ever you want... Please give details (especially an example of your XML)

Comment: I want to add the XML data from the XML-file into a SQL-server table.

Comment: Would you please answer the questions of my comment? Your last comment doesn't add any news to this... Just think with a SO user's head... We have no idea what you really want...

Comment: I set the sql-server as a tag because sql-server is related to the topic.

I want to read an existing XML file into my sql-server database table, that is what I want. No, DataTable is NOT an existing table, it's just something I  assumed was right but isn't. I'm gonna remove DataTable from my question.

An example of my XML is included in the question.

Comment: OK, and how is the structure of the table you want to insert this into?

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I cannot know, which values map to which column I'll give you just an example how to do this. But it should be easy to add the rest following this template.

With a codle like this you might insert the values into your table.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(PersonalIdentityNumber, ... , FirstName,MiddleName,LastName, ...)
SELECT Person.value('(PersonId/PersonNr)[1]','varchar(max)') AS PersonalIdentityNumber
      ,... 
      ,Person.value('(Namn/Fornamn)[1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstName
      ,Person.value('(Namn/Mellannamn)[1]','varchar(max)') AS MiddleName
      ,Person.value('(Namn/Efternamn)[1]','varchar(max)') AS LastName
      ,...

FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE/FolkbokforingspostTYPE/Personpost') AS The(Person)
```

Actually there is no need to name the columns of your `SELECT` as I did it here. With the `INSERT INTO` you define a column list and the `SELECT` below must just return these columns in the right count and order.

You must be aware, that XPath is very strict with your spelling and is **case sensitive** There won't be an error, just a NULL if you do something wrong.

If you are not experienced with XML queries: Just put a `--` in front of the `INSERT INTO` and let the result of the `SELECT` be displayed to you. When everything is fine, remove the `--` and the data should be inserted into your table.

To get an easy call from your application you might put this into a `Stored Procedure` and pass in the XML as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you. Just one question. Where does the `Person.` come from in that `SELECT`?

Comment: @Simon.S, When you query an XML  you very often use `.nodes(XPath)` to start with your "navigation". `.nodes()` itself needs to be aliased. So - right at the end you find `AS The(Person)`. You might take this as table's name and column name.

Comment: Ohh I see. But isn't it supposed to get the path to the XML-file somewhere?

Comment: I was thinking of a stored procedure like `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddPersonData(@xml XML) ...` where you hand in the XML from your application. I would rather not read the XML from the file system out of SQL code. This is possible, but can lead to big troubles if your SQL Server is running on another machine...