# Mapping XML to Database table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I'm writing a program that maps XML data to a database table.

This is how I tried it:

```
    namespace TESTMAPPNING2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test();
        }


        static void Test()
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            XmlReader xmlFile;
            string sql = null;

            //The XML-tags that i want to insert in the table columns
            string PersonalIdentityNumber = null;
            string ProtectedIdentity = null;
            int ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber = 0;
            string UnregistrationReason = null;
            DateTime? UnregistrationDate = null;
            string MessageComputerComputer = null;
            int GivenNameNumber = 0;
            string FirstName = null;
            string LastName = null;
            string NotifyName = null;
            DateTime? NationalRegistrationDate = null;
            string NationalRegistrationCountyCode = null;
            string NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = null;
            string NationalRegistrationCoAddress = null;
            string NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = null;
            string NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = null;
            string NationalRegistrationPostCode = null;
            string NationalRegistrationCity = null;
            string NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress = null;
            string NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode = null;
            string NationalRegistrationNotifyCity = null;
            string ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = null;
            string ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 = null;
            string ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 = null;
            string ForeignDistrubtionCountry = null;
            string ForeignDate = null;
            string BirthCountyCode = null;
            string BirthParish = null;
            string ForeignBirthCity = null;
            string CitizenshipCode = null;
            DateTime? CitizenshipDate = null;
            string Email = null;
            string Telephone = null;
            string Mobiletelephone = null;
            string Gender = null;
            string NotNewsPaper = null;
            string Note = null;
            string StatusCode = null;
            string NationalRegistrationCode = null;
            DateTime? RegistrationDate = null;
            DateTime? LastUpdatedFromNavet = null;
            string TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1 = null;
            string TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2 = null;
            string TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3 = null;
            string TemporaryDistrubtionCountry = null;
            string Password = null;
            string VisibilityLevel = null;
            string LastChangedBy = null;
            DateTime? LastChangedDate = null;
            int SeamanIdentity = 0;
            string Category = null;







            connetionString = "Data Source=tsrv2062;Initial Catalog=Bums;User ID=BumsUser;Password=2tusen7Bums";

            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("navetout.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);

            int i = 0;
            connection.Open();
            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                PersonalIdentityNumber = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();



                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Seamen(PersonalIdentityNumber, ProtectedIdentity, ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber,UnregistrationReason,UnregistrationDate,MessageComputerComputer,GivenNameNumber,FirstName,LastName,NotifyName,NationalRegistrationDate,NationalRegistrationCountyCode,NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode,NationalRegistrationCoAddress,NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1,NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2,NationalRegistrationPostCode,NationalRegistrationCity,NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress,NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode,NationalRegistrationNotifyCity,ForeignDistrubtionAddress1,ForeignDistrubtionAddress2,ForeignDistrubtionAddress3,ForeignDistrubtionCountry,ForeignDate,BirthCountyCode,BirthParish,ForeignBirthCity,CitizenshipCode,CitizenshipDate,Email,Telephone,Mobiletelephone,Gender,NotNewsPaper,Note,StatusCode,NationalRegistrationCode,RegistrationDate,LastUpdatedFromNavet,TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1,TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2,TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3 ,TemporaryDistrubtionCountry,Password,VisibilityLevel,LastChangedBy,LastChangedDate, SeamanIdentity, Category) values(@PersonalIdentityNumber, @ProtectedIdentity, @ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber,@UnregistrationReason,@UnregistrationDate,@MessageComputerComputer,@GivenNameNumber,@FirstName,@LastName,@NotifyName,@NationalRegistrationDate,@NationalRegistrationCountyCode,@NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode,@NationalRegistrationCoAddress,@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1,@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2,@NationalRegistrationPostCode,@NationalRegistrationCity,@NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress,@NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode,@NationalRegistrationNotifyCity,@ForeignDistrubtionAddress1,@ForeignDistrubtionAddress2,@ForeignDistrubtionAddress3,@ForeignDistrubtionCountry,@ForeignDate,@BirthCountyCode,@BirthParish,@ForeignBirthCity,@CitizenshipCode,@CitizenshipDate,@Email,@Telephone,@Mobiletelephone,@Gender,@NotNewsPaper,@Note,StatusCode,@NationalRegistrationCode,@RegistrationDate,@LastUpdatedFromNavet,@TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1,@TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2,@TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3 ,@TemporaryDistrubtionCountry,@Password,@VisibilityLevel,@LastChangedBy,@LastChangedDate, @SeamanIdentity, @Category)", connection);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", PersonalIdentityNumber);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProtectedIdentity", ProtectedIdentity);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber", ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationReason", UnregistrationReason);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationDate", UnregistrationDate);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MessageComputerComputer", MessageComputerComputer);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenNameNumber", GivenNameNumber);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NotifyName", NotifyName);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDate", NationalRegistrationDate);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCountyCode", NationalRegistrationCountyCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode", NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCoAddress", NationalRegistrationCoAddress);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1", NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2", NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationPostCode", NationalRegistrationPostCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCity", NationalRegistrationCity);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress", NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode", NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationNotifyCity", NationalRegistrationNotifyCity);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDistrubtionAddress1", ForeignDistrubtionAddress1);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDistrubtionAddress2", ForeignDistrubtionAddress2);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDistrubtionAddress3", ForeignDistrubtionAddress3);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDistrubtionCountry", ForeignDistrubtionCountry);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDate", ForeignDate);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthCountyCode", BirthCountyCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthParish", BirthParish);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignBirthCity", ForeignBirthCity);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipCode", CitizenshipCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipDate", CitizenshipDate);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone ", Telephone);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobiletelephone", Mobiletelephone);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NotNewsPaper", NotNewsPaper);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", Note);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusCode", StatusCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCode", NationalRegistrationCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationDate", RegistrationDate);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdatedFromNavet", LastUpdatedFromNavet);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1", TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2", TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3", TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemporaryDistrubtionCountry", TemporaryDistrubtionCountry);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisibilityLevel", VisibilityLevel);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedBy", LastChangedBy);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedDate", LastChangedDate);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeamanIdentity", SeamanIdentity);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Category);



                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

I get error on the `command1.ExecuteNonQuery();`

The error says

> The name "NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

The XML `navetout.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>194903188953</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>20</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>Erik Lennart</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Enberg</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20060512</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>25</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>14</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>PÅLÄNGE 6:38</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>STORVÄGEN 65</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>95204</PostNr>
          <Postort>PÅLÄNG</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>250015520</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>2416233</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>22143838</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>25</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>NEDERKALIX</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>   </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>   <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
    <TilldelatPersonNrSamordningsNr>195405869370</TilldelatPersonNrSamordningsNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Fornamn styrkt="J">Eduardo Metran</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn styrkt="J">Garcia</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum xsi:nil="true" />
        <LanKod>14</LanKod>
        <KommunKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning xsi:nil="true" />
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser />
      <Fodelse>
        <OrtUtlandet>
          <FodelseortUtland styrkt="J">Sta Cruz Zambales</FodelseortUtland>
          <Fodelseland>FILIPPINERNA</Fodelseland>
        </OrtUtlandet>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod styrkt="J">PH</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>   </FolkbokforingspostTYPE> </ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE>
```

Why do I get the error?

And most importantly, how can I "translate" the XML-tags to match the table columns?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing all the fields. You'll have to add the parameters for the rest.

```
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress", yourData);
// same for the rest fields
```

Also, `@` is missing in the sql after the first parameter.

Comment: What do you mean that the @ is missing in the first parameter? I do have it in `command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", PersonalIdentityNumber);`

Comment: `@` means it's a parameter and you'll need to supply a value later. You only have `@` for the first parameter(PersonalIdentityNumber) in the sql. It's missing for the rest. Without it, the parameter is considered as a column name, that's why you got an error saying `Column names are not permitted`.

Comment: Yeah but the value is the local varable after the parameter.. Please see my updated question

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. I will add it too

Comment: The question is.. Is `PersonalIdentityNumber = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();` getting value from the XML-tags?

Answer (score 0):

in your long code line you find

```
 values(@PersonalIdentityNumber, NationalRegistrationNotifyDistribution ...
```

the first is with `@` the second is not.

You must know where you use the names of your columns and where you use the names of your variables.

You might use literal values within `VALUES`, but - if you use parameters (with the `@` you must declare **all** of them and add them with values to your command objects. For testing purpose you are adding just this:

```
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", ...
```

Either use literal values for your test or add all parameters and use proper naming with `@`

Comment: Is it possible to add the XML-tags into those local variables so that I can insert the values into the databse table?

Comment: @Simon.S, The XML is a string (technically, there are specialities...). You can define a SQL parameter of type `VARCHAR(MAX)`, pass in the string and cast it to XML within your SQL code. Doing so you might run into problems with special characters, which'd need encoding for XML (e.g. `& -> &amp;`)... Better was to define the SQL parameter as XML so the encoding should be done during pass over. In both cases you'd have to shred your XML within SQL code. [How you do this? I gave you answers already...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36037496/5089204) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to write serialization classes with all the XML content, then deserialize it (read the XML into classes). Best is to use inner classes where the XML has inner nodes, rather than just a flat XML.

I think this is only a tryout, so the next training point will probably be to split up the single "monster" table in the DB into logical linked units (aka Normalization).